# Set layout constraints in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been searching all day, through forums, videos and web pages, if there is any way to set constraints when using `SpriteKit` in `GameScene.sks`.

For example, if I wanted to set objects certain distances from the edge of the screen for EVERY device, what do I do? Is there anything similar to `UIKit`'s constraints?

Here is my Pong game so far, just to learn Sprite Kit:
[image]

Can this be set in the Attributes Inspector some how, or is there any way to set this pragmatically?

Thanks for any help on this, or any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SKConstraints for this. For example create a distance constraint to the border.

First specify a range to the left border:

```
let rangeToLeftBorder = SKRange(lowerLimit: 10.0, upperLimit: 150.0)
```

Then create a constraint:

```
let distanceConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(rangeToLeftBorder, toNode: YourBorderSprite)
```

Assing the constraint to your sprite:

```
yourSprite.constraints = [distanceConstraint]
```